# Tradingview alert: trigger in the last 30 minutes if condition is met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want ot create an alert which shall trigger in the last 30 min of the day (EDT) if a certain condition is met: if the close of the actual 5min candle - the actual day's low / (day's High - day's low) is larger than 0.7, i.e.: (close - Low)/(High - Low) > 0.7.

Here's the code, which does not trigger:

```
//@version=5
indicator("ClosingAlert")

High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high)
Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low)
Open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)
HL = High - Low
InSession(sess) => not na(time("5", sess, "America/New_York")[1])
sellClose = ((close - Low)/HL > 0.7) and InSession("1530-1600") 

alertcondition(condition=sellClose, message="Sell Signal")
```

What am I missing? Are the different time fames wrongly coded?

Comment: I just added a couple of lines to stop debug. Your script [looks fine.](https://www.tradingview.com/x/eoUtmT1C/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't fully understand why it does not trigger but I found a workaround:
I skipped the InSession row but calculated the close in a 5 min frame and modified the sellClose condition:

```
//@version=5
indicator("ClosingAlert")
High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high)
Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low)
Open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)
Close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)
HL = High - Low
sellClose = ((Close - Low)/HL > 0.9) and (time_close - timenow) < 1800000
alertcondition(condition=sellClose, message="Sell Signal")
```

Since the time is reported in ms, 1800000 corresponds to 30min between the closing time and the actual time.